# Extract JSON Payload with Citrus Framework

Tags: java, maven, testng, citrus-framework

I am trying to get some information from JSON responses using Citrus Framework, but I am not sure of how does the .extractFromPayload method works. For example, I make a GET request and the JSON response is:

> ["as:s.7635a8e95e1b707d","as:s.c585a8e92874e4a9","as:s.8935a8e9848d14ce","as:s.f885a8ebb1887346","as:s.0123456789abcdef","as:s.7b55a8e96a74893d","as:s.b3f5a8d9b3971120","as:s.5f05a8e936ed377d","as:s.6f5d3e05670a4b448bf9ba81d1172307","as:s.de07ada3dd724347a26fdd93231491e2","as:s.f705a8ebaa3e9e74"]

So the question is how can I get one of those keys? And if I need only the alphanumerical part, i.e 7635a8e95e1b707d, how can I parse it?.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload is a JSON array of Strings. You are able to access a value in that array using JsonPath expression and `extractFromPayload` method. After extracting the whole value as a test variable using JsonPath you may use a Citrus function like `citrus:substring()`or `citrus:substringAfter()` in a second operation.

```
receive(someEndpoint)
    .extractFromPayload("$.[0]", "foo");

echo("citrus:substringAfter(${foo} ,'.')");
```